Nested Components each with Repeating Elements
I'm working on a dynamic form where people can create questions for a survey.
The main form allows Questions to be added, and each question may have 1:N conditions and answers added to it.
The main template looks like this:
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Question from 'components/templates/question';
import { Button, Form } from 'react-bootstrap';

const Templates = () => {
  const [questions, setQuestions] = useState([Question()]);
 
  const increase = () => {
    setQuestions([...questions, Question()]);
  };

  return (
    <form>
      {questions.map((component, index) => (
        <React.Fragment key={index}>
          { component }
        </React.Fragment>
      ))}
      <Button variant='success' onClick={increase}> + </Button>
    </form>
  );
};

And the Questions which contain incrementable, repeatable conditions looks like this:
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Button, Card, Form } from 'react-bootstrap';
import Condition from './condition';

const Question = () => {
    const [conditions, setConditions] = useState([Condition()]);

    const increaseC = () => {
        setConditions([...conditions, Condition()]);
    };

  return (
    <Card className="mb-4">
        <Card.Body>
            <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="questionTitle">
                <Form.Label>Question Title</Form.Label>
                <Form.Control type="text" placeholder="What is a simple name for this data point?" />
            </Form.Group>
            <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="questionDescription">
                <Form.Label>Question Description</Form.Label>
                <Form.Control type="text" placeholder="What are you looking for?" />
            </Form.Group>
            <h5 class="card-title">Conditions</h5>
            <h6 class="card-subtitle text-muted">Are there conditions for when this text is displayed?</h6>
            {conditions.map((component, index) => (
                <React.Fragment key={index}>
                { component }
                </React.Fragment>
            ))}
            <br />
            <Button variant='outline-success' size="sm" onClick={increaseC}>+</Button>
        </Card.Body>
    </Card>
  );
}

export default Question;

As you can imagine, this does not work. I've seen passing arguments between components, but for the life of me I cannot figure out how to have multiple states that map component collections.

If you don't event need any props, then why not just keep the array length as your state?

Also this violate React, [Question()] keeping component inside the React. use an array instead

Hey @Wesley, have you tried approaching the problem as suggested by this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/78441068/8997321?

There are multiple approaches you could take here. The main idea is to store the data of conditions instead of the components themselves. You should make your <Condition /> a controlled component, which takes the data as a prop, and provides onChange callback, to update the condition once it's edited.
interface ConditionData {
  // condition-related data
}

...

const Question = () => {
  // store a list of conditions' data
  const [conditions, setConditions] = useState<ConditionData>([]);

  const increaseC = () => {
      setConditions([...conditions, { ...initialConditionData }]);
  };

  const onConditionChange = useCallback((data: ConditionData, index: number) => {
      // Update condition that changed on the given index
      setConditions(conditions => 
        conditions.map((condition, conditionIndex) =>
          conditionIndex === index ? data : condition
        )
      );
  }, []);

  return (
    ...
    {conditions.map((data, index) => (
      <Condition
        key={index}
        data={data}
        onChange={(data) => onConditionChange(data, index)} 
      />
    ))}
    ...
  )
}

Ideally, you should generate a unique ID for a new condition, so that keys of unchanged conditions don't change once you remove the condition. It's a simple modification of the code above.
interface ConditionData {
  id: number;
  // condition-related data
}

function* createConditionGenerator() {
  let id = 0;
  while (true) {
    yield { ...initialConditionData, id }
    id++;
  }
}

const generateNewCondition = createConditionGenerator();

const Question = () => {
  const [conditions, setConditions] = useState<ConditionData>([generateNewCondition.next().value]);


  const increaseC = () => {
    setConditions([...conditions, generateNewCondition.next().value ]);
  };

  const onConditionChange = useCallback((data: ConditionData) => {
      // Update condition that changed on the given id
      setConditions(conditions => 
        conditions.map((condition) =>
          condition.id === data.id ? data : condition
        )
      );
  }, []);

  return (
    ...
    {conditions.map((data) => (
      <Condition
        key={data.id}
        data={data}
        onChange={onConditionChange} 
      />
    ))}
    ...
  )
}

